# Should a function that returns a context-managed object be decorated by `@contextmanager`?

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

Say I have a function that returns a context-managed object, here a `tempfile.TemporaryFile`:

```
import tempfile

def make_temp_file():
    """Create a temporary file. Best used with a context manager"""
    tmpfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    return tmpfile
```

Is this safe as is or should this be wrapped with a context manager?

```
import tempfile
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def make_temp_file():
    """Create a temporary file. Best used with a context manager"""
    tmpfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    return tmpfile
```

My confusion comes from the linter pylint who still insist the first example triggers a [`consider-using-with` rule](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/refactor/consider-using-with.html).

Comment: No, you are already passing back a context manager object (it as a `__enter__` method) and you don't have to "recontextize" it. I ran your example through pylint without getting that warning. Can you post the pylint output you got?

Comment: Feel free to add an answer for your first sentence. About pylint, I am using version 2.16.2. My initially example did not cause the warning. I have updated the question with an example that does. This seems to be a false positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function already returns a context object (something with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods) and does not need to be rewrapped. That wouldn't change anything.

The idea of `with` is that the context manager's `__exit__` will be called when the `with` suite finishes, even if there is an error. But algorithms don't always fit conveniently into suites as your code indicates. If you can't use a context manager, you need some other mechanism to ensure that *something* closes the object.

As an example, suppose your function performed some other task before `return`. It could hit an exception and terminate before anybody has a chance to close the object. In that case you would do

```
def make_temp_file():
    tmpfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    try:
        do_other_things()
    except:
        tmpfile.close()
        raise
```

If your function doesn't do anything after creating the object, you can skip the intermediate variable and likely get rid of the lint warning while you are at it. From the [pylint doc](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/refactor/consider-using-with.html) the warning is suppressed when *the call result is returned from the enclosing function*.

```
def make_temp_file():
    return tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
```

Note that since you return a context object that needs to be closed, the same issues apply to the thing that calls the function. Either that should be a `with` or should have some other mechanism to make sure the object is closed when done.

Comment: check your pylint link, it doesn't seem to point to their docs.